# Javascript for loop skips last element

Tags: javascript

i have array from which am deleting certain elements on base of certain conditions and when i delete element i restart for loop because index is refreshed.

```
var k;
for( k=0 ; k < this.j_data.length;k++){
     if(condition === true){
       this.j_data.splice(k, 1);
       k = 0; // restart
     }
}
```

my array this.j_data have two element both should be deleted by splice however after first element deleted , the last one is skipped by loop.

any idea what am missing

Comment: well, `k++` gets run before the `k <` check, so, set `k = -1` instead

Comment: Consider using `filter` instead: `this.j_data = this.j_data.filter(function(item){return !condition})` unless you have special reason to modify original array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Jaromanda X

k++ occur first so k=-1 fix the issue

```
var k;
for( k=0 ; k < this.j_data.length;k++){
     if(condition === true){
       this.j_data.splice(k, 1);
       k = -1; // restart
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you get the last `k` also beacause when `k=1` it stops the loop

```
var k;
for( k=0 ; k <= this.j_data.length;k++){
     if(condition === true){
       this.j_data.splice(k, 1);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop always increment the index after an iteration, so when you set `k=0` on next iteration it will be setted to `1`, so you'll never remove the element in pos "1" (second element of the array).

I think you should use a different kind of loop, a `do/while` in order to test the condition after the execution of the block of code inside the loop, see follow:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log("Before: " + arr);

(function(j_data, condition){
  var k=0;
  do {
       if(condition === true){
         j_data.splice(k, 1);
         k = 0; // restart
       }else{
         k++;
       }
  } while(k < j_data.length);
})(arr, true);

console.log("After: " + arr);
```