# JavaScript For loop ending before the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm styling a blog where each blog is tagged with a relevant tag.
The style of the blogs varies depending on which tag is applied to that blog.

My For loop is ending before it reaches the last blog on the page and I have no idea why.

I looked around and found this: [Javascript for loop skips last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275016/javascript-for-loop-skips-last-element) I tried the suggestions in that thread but they didn't work.

Things I've tried:

- i = -1
- i <= postTagArray.length
- swapping the for loop to a do/while loop (js i used at the bottom)
- declaring i before the loop (setting it to both 0 and -1)

Here's my full script:

```
//declare arrays containing every instance of each class
var postTagArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-tag');
var postTitleArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-title');
var postButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-button');
          
//declare variable containing the preset tags
var Security = "/ Security";
var Cleaning = "/ Cleaning";
var Safety = "/ Safety";
var Hospitality = "/ Hospitality";
var Logistics = "/ Logistics";
var General = "/ General";
          
for (var i=0; i <= postTagArray.length; i++) {
  //bring in the HTML of the element
  var tag=postTagArray[i].innerHTML;
            
  //compare HTML of the element and the preset tag
  //then assigns a value of 0 if they match, or 1 if they don't
  var secResult = tag.localeCompare(Security);
  var cleResult = tag.localeCompare(Cleaning);
  var safResult = tag.localeCompare(Safety);
  var hosResult = tag.localeCompare(Hospitality);
  var logResult = tag.localeCompare(Logistics);
  var genResult = tag.localeCompare(General);
            
  //find the result that matches (that equals 0) and assign styling accordingly
  if (secResult=="0"){
     postTagArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
     postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
     postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#0085CA";
  }
  if (cleResult=="0"){
     postTagArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
     postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
     postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#6CC24A";
  }
  if (safResult=="0"){
     postTagArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
     postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
     postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#EF3340";
  }
  if (hosResult=="0"){
     postTagArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
     postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
     postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#D9027D";
  }
  if (logResult=="0"){
     postTagArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
     postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
     postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#685BC7";
  }
  if (genResult=="0"){
     postTagArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
     postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
     postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#959595";
  }
}
```

and here's the output:
[image: blog output]

As you can see, the last blog isn't being assigned the same styling as the other Cleaning blog.

This is the do/while loop I tried to use:

```
var i = 0;
do {
   //bring in the HTML of the element
   var tag=postTagArray[i].innerHTML;

   //compare HTML of the element and the preset tag
   //then assigns a value of 0 if they match, or 1 if they don't
   var secResult = tag.localeCompare(Security);
   var cleResult = tag.localeCompare(Cleaning);
   var safResult = tag.localeCompare(Safety);
   var hosResult = tag.localeCompare(Hospitality);
   var logResult = tag.localeCompare(Logistics);
   var genResult = tag.localeCompare(General);

   //find the result that matches (that equals 0) and assign styling accordingly
   if (secResult=="0"){
      postTagArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
      postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
      postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#0085CA";
   }
   if (cleResult=="0"){
      postTagArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
      postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
      postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#6CC24A";
   }
   if (safResult=="0"){
      postTagArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
      postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
      postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#EF3340";
   }
   if (hosResult=="0"){
      postTagArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
      postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
      postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#D9027D";
   }
   if (logResult=="0"){
      postTagArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
      postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
      postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#685BC7";
   }
   if (genResult=="0"){
      postTagArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
      postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
      postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#959595";
   }
   i++;
} while (i <= postTagArray.length);
```

I'm out of ideas, and don't know why the things I tried didn't work, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: thanks to @JudeMaranga and @Wyck I discovered that the last element isn't being loaded into the array at all. It's loading the first element twice and not reaching the last element. Here's the console.log output of the array:

[image: consolelog output]

And when I printed out the 0, 1, 2 elements of the array, element 2 was returned as undefined

UPDATE 2: here's a link to the dev page I'm building on: http://3441160.hs-sites.com/blog

I've also recreated it in here:

```html
<body>
    <div>
         <script>
        //declare arrays containing every instance of each class
        var postTagArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-tag');
        var postTitleArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-title');
        var postButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-button');
                  
        //declare variable containing the preset tags
        var Security = "/ Security";
        var Cleaning = "/ Cleaning";
        var Safety = "/ Safety";
        var Hospitality = "/ Hospitality";
        var Logistics = "/ Logistics";
        var General = "/ General";
                  
        var i;
        for (let i=0; i < postTagArray.length; ++i) {
            //bring in the HTML of the element
            var tag=postTagArray[i].innerHTML;
                    
            //compare HTML of the element and the preset tag
            //then assigns a value of 0 if they match, or 1 if they don't
            var secResult = tag.localeCompare(Security);
            var cleResult = tag.localeCompare(Cleaning);
            var safResult = tag.localeCompare(Safety);
            var hosResult = tag.localeCompare(Hospitality);
            var logResult = tag.localeCompare(Logistics);
            var genResult = tag.localeCompare(General);
                    
            //find the result that matches (that equals 0) and assign styling accordingly
            if (secResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#0085CA";
            }
            if (cleResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#6CC24A";
            }
            if (safResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#EF3340";
            }
            if (hosResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#D9027D";
            }
            if (logResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#685BC7";
            }
            if (genResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#959595";
            }
        }
        //print contents of postTagArray to the console for testing purposes
        for (let i = 0; i < postTagArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(i, postTagArray[i]);
        }
    </script>
        <h1 class="blog-tag">/ Cleaning</h1>
        <h2 class="blog-title">Title</h2>
        <button class="blog-button">button</button>
    </div>
    <div>
         <script>
        //declare arrays containing every instance of each class
        var postTagArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-tag');
        var postTitleArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-title');
        var postButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-button');
                  
        //declare variable containing the preset tags
        var Security = "/ Security";
        var Cleaning = "/ Cleaning";
        var Safety = "/ Safety";
        var Hospitality = "/ Hospitality";
        var Logistics = "/ Logistics";
        var General = "/ General";
                  
        var i;
        for (let i=0; i < postTagArray.length; ++i) {
            //bring in the HTML of the element
            var tag=postTagArray[i].innerHTML;
                    
            //compare HTML of the element and the preset tag
            //then assigns a value of 0 if they match, or 1 if they don't
            var secResult = tag.localeCompare(Security);
            var cleResult = tag.localeCompare(Cleaning);
            var safResult = tag.localeCompare(Safety);
            var hosResult = tag.localeCompare(Hospitality);
            var logResult = tag.localeCompare(Logistics);
            var genResult = tag.localeCompare(General);
                    
            //find the result that matches (that equals 0) and assign styling accordingly
            if (secResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#0085CA";
            }
            if (cleResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#6CC24A";
            }
            if (safResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#EF3340";
            }
            if (hosResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#D9027D";
            }
            if (logResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#685BC7";
            }
            if (genResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#959595";
            }
        }
        //print contents of postTagArray to the console for testing purposes
        for (let i = 0; i < postTagArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(i, postTagArray[i]);
        }
    </script>
        <h1 class="blog-tag">/ Safety</h1>
        <h2 class="blog-title">Title</h2>
        <button class="blog-button">button</button>
    </div>
    <div>
         <script>
        //declare arrays containing every instance of each class
        var postTagArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-tag');
        var postTitleArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-title');
        var postButtonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('blog-button');
                  
        //declare variable containing the preset tags
        var Security = "/ Security";
        var Cleaning = "/ Cleaning";
        var Safety = "/ Safety";
        var Hospitality = "/ Hospitality";
        var Logistics = "/ Logistics";
        var General = "/ General";
                  
        var i;
        for (let i=0; i < postTagArray.length; ++i) {
            //bring in the HTML of the element
            var tag=postTagArray[i].innerHTML;
                    
            //compare HTML of the element and the preset tag
            //then assigns a value of 0 if they match, or 1 if they don't
            var secResult = tag.localeCompare(Security);
            var cleResult = tag.localeCompare(Cleaning);
            var safResult = tag.localeCompare(Safety);
            var hosResult = tag.localeCompare(Hospitality);
            var logResult = tag.localeCompare(Logistics);
            var genResult = tag.localeCompare(General);
                    
            //find the result that matches (that equals 0) and assign styling accordingly
            if (secResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#0085CA";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#0085CA";
            }
            if (cleResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#6CC24A";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#6CC24A";
            }
            if (safResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#EF3340";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#EF3340";
            }
            if (hosResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#D9027D";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#D9027D";
            }
            if (logResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#685BC7";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#685BC7";
            }
            if (genResult=="0"){
                postTagArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
                postTitleArray[i].style.color = "#959595";
                postButtonArray[i].style.background = "#959595";
            }
        }
        //print contents of postTagArray to the console for testing purposes
        for (let i = 0; i < postTagArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(i, postTagArray[i]);
        }
    </script>
        <h1 class="blog-tag">/ Cleaning</h1>
        <h2 class="blog-title">Title</h2>
        <button class="blog-button">button</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you try printing the contents of `postTagArray` in the console by doing console.log and share the output here?

Comment: Is it always skipping the last element? what happens if you duplicate the last element and run the loop?

Comment: by the way it is `i < postTagArray.length` not `i <= postTagArray.length` in the loop condition.

Comment: @alan_jouhar yes it's always the last element, I tried duplicating the last element and got the same result.

Comment: @JudeMaranga I'm not sure how to do that in the environment I'm working in but I did check the contents of the array by printing it out.

Turns out the last element isn't being loaded into the array at all. I don't understand why that would be the case though, the "blog-tag" array should pull in all instances of that class. And I double checked, the last element does also have that class applied.

Comment: You need to change `i <= postTagArray.length` to `i < postTagArray.length`.  An array with length 3 has 3 valid indices, which are: 0, 1, and 2.  The element at index 3 should be undefined.  The condition for a loop that starts at 0 needs to succeed when i is 2, so it will process the last element (with index 2) but fail when i is 3 so it does not try to handle the undefined element beyond the end of the array.  In general, the pattern is: `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) { console.log(i, array[i]); }`

Comment: @Wyck I tested that and the output of the array was 0, 0, 1 (edited the question to include the image) so it seems that it's doubling up on the first one and not reaching the last one

Comment: From your code nothing seems to be incorrect. Except loop statement, which already mentioned by others, just check once again with `for (let i = 0; i < postTagArray.length; i++) { console.log(i)}`.... Note increment operator has been changed. If issue still persist, we need more of your code or a working example, that will illustrate your problem

Comment: @Kenny here's a link to the dev pageI'm working on:
http://3441160.hs-sites.com/blog

It's a hubspot site so to rule out any hubspot related things I also replicated the layout of the code in the snippet in the question. Super simplistic but it recreates it and still has the same problem. So nothing to do with hubspot I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

so in the end it was a structural problem.

I originally had my script above the blog post, and hubspot was repeating it on every post.

I solved it by moving the script to the bottom of the page.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions